# How can I click on this drop-down menu with help of selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, junit, cucumber, gherkin

I have a problem with the drop-down menu from wikipedia. With appears when I insert some letters. How can I say cucumber/selenium to click on "Baum".

[image]

I do this to learn selenium.

Here are my steps. First I go to the german wikipedia:

```
@Given("^You want to search for \"Baum\" on \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void youWantToSearchForOnWikipediaOrg(String page) throws Throwable
{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
            "C:\\...\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://"+page+"/wiki/Wikipedia:Hauptseite");
}
```

Then I search for the word "Baum":

```
@Then("^You tipp the letters \"([^\"]*)\", \"([^\"]*)\" and \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void youTippTheLettersAnd(String letter1, String letter2, String letter3) throws Throwable
{
    Thread.sleep(5);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='searchInput']")).sendKeys(letter1);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='searchInput']")).sendKeys(letter2);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='searchInput']")).sendKeys(letter3);
    Thread.sleep(25);
}
```

Now a dropdown menu appaers an I want to click on the entry "Baum".

```
@Then("^Click on the appearing Baum$")
public void clickOnTheAppearing() throws Throwable
{
    //Thread.sleep(50);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a/div")).click();
}
```

But xpath can't find the element. I try different xpath and css, but nothing helps...

Examples:

> //*[@classname='mw-searchSuggest-linkinput']//*[text()='Baum']
>
> /html/body/div[6]/div/a[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grhkL.png)/div/span
>
> /html/body/div[6]/div/a[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grhkL.png)/div
>
> body > div.suggestions > div > a:nth-child(1) > div > span

Comment: kindly share HTML code in plain text along with your current code attempts and stack trace if any.

Comment: The html is wikipedia. my code is now in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify more info to the a tag saying which value to select. So you need to use something like :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='Baun']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the text in xpath along with keyword *contains*

```
//*[contains(text(),'Baun')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try these:

```
String text = "Baum"; /* text you want to select, may be you can parameterize this in your Gherkin step */
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@title,'" + text + "')]");
```

Alternatively, you can look for all suggestion results listed, iterate them and choose the one you want like:

```
List<WebElement> suggestionResults = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a/div[@class='suggestions-result']");
for(WebElement result : suggestionResults){
    if(results.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(text) || result.getText().contains(text)){
       result.click();
       break;
    }
}
```

Advanced method: If you want to select the specific text after your search text 'Baum', then you can go for:

```
//a[.//span[text()='Baum'] and .//text()[contains(.,'Welch algorithm')]]
```

First condition is for your search text match 'Baum' and second condition for your desired text selection 'Welch algorithm'. Again make these 2 inputs as parameters driven from your gherkin step definition.